# C# Read from text file separated by commas into 2d array

Tags: c#, streamreader

I currently have this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("answers.txt"))
{
    for (iCountLine = 0; iCountLine < 10; iCountLine++)
    {
         for (iCountAnswer = 0; iCountAnswer < 4; iCountAnswer++)
         {
             sQuestionAnswers[iCountLine, iCountAnswer] = 
         }
    }
}
```

My text file is formatted like this (10 lines of text, with 4 items on each line separated by commas):

> ```
> example, example, example, example 
> 123, 123, 123, 123
> ```

I'm not sure what I need after the "=" in the for loop to get it to read and split the contents of the text file into the 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure what I need after the "=" in the for loop

There's also a line missing above it:

```
var tokens = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
```

Now the line with `=` would look like this:

```
sQuestionAnswers[iCountLine, iCountAnswer] = tokens[iCountAnswer];
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use `StreamReader`, but it's short and easy to understand:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data.txt");
        string[][] jaggedArray = lines.Select(line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Rows are extracted by `ReadAllLines` according to newline. Columns values are extracted by calling `Split` on every line. It returns jagged array that you can use similarly to multidimensional array, also jagged arrays are generally faster than multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
string line;

using (var sr = new StreamReader("answers.txt"))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int iCountLine = 0; iCountLine < 10; iCountLine++)
        {
            var answers = line.Split(',');
            for (int iCountAnswer = 0; iCountAnswer < 4; iCountAnswer++)
            {
                sQuestionAnswers[iCountLine, iCountAnswer] = answers[iCountAnswer];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to change the approach.

Go over the file using ReadLine() method of a StreamReader class.
Then split the read line using Split(new[]{','}), and this will give you every single record.
And finally the sQuestionAnswers[iCountLine, iCountAnswer] will be: the just Split array's [iCountAnswer]'s record.