# loading textfile in to two dimensional array C# GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, windows-forms-designer

So most things ive read about loading textfiles in windows form shows you loading it into a single dimension string array. but I have some features id like to do that would work much better if it were a two dimensional array. in this example i have a book catalog with isbn, author, title, year, price. I want to be able to compile data about most expensive and least expensive book (which I'm able to do already from the array that i have for user entry), and be able to search the array by title, isbn, etc. I also am displaying it in a multicolumn listview.

Heres what I have for loading the textfile (which is new records separated by new lines, and it is tab ('\t') delimited) and displaying it in the multicolumn listview. What would I need to do to load this into a 2D array? and how would i display it? any help would be great.

```
static FileStream textFile = new FileStream("booklist.txt",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(textFile);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textFile);
    const char DELIM = '\t';
    //string[] booksTextArray;
    string line = "";
    string[] items;
    ListViewItem listItem;

// the load button
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // loads text file with existing book catalog
        while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            items = line.Split('\t'); //Split the line.
            listItem = new ListViewItem(); //"Row" object.
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    listItem.Text = items[i]; //First item is not a "subitem".
                }
                else
                {
                    listItem.SubItems.Add(items[i]); //Add it to the "Row" object.
                }
            }
            listView1.Items.Add(listItem); //Add the row object to the listview.
            status_label.Text = "Load successful.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The object you want is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025468/c-sharp-read-from-text-file-separated-by-commas-into-2d-array. Do a search for questions about working with comma separated files. You'll get lots of info.